# Create a new record with certain values after updating an existing record - Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table "1208Data" in Access 2013. It has the following fields

- ID (Autonumber)
- Store
- Customer
- Invoice Date
- Amount
- Notes
- Inv/Pmt
- Paid

When a record is marked Paid (update "Paid" from blank to "Paid"), then I also create a new record, a copy of the same record, but changing "Date", Reversing the "Amount", changing "Notes" to the check number, changing "Inv/Pmt" to "Pmt"

In the table before:

> ID....Store...Customer...........................Invoice..Date...........Amount...Notes..........Inv/Pmt    Paid
>
> 4010..26.....APPLE CATERING, INC...6012.....10/9/2014....632.50...110 Lg Ch....Inv

In the table after:

> ID......Store..Customer.........................Invoice..Date..........Amount.....Notes...........Inv/Pmt....Paid
>
> 4011....26....APPLE CATERING, INC..6012....10/9/2014.....632.50....110 Lg Ch....Inv...........Paid
>
> 4012....26....APPLE CATERING, INC..6012....10/16/2014...-632.50...ck # 1234.....Pmt.........Paid

Is there a way to do this with a form or ???

Currently I'm having to search for the Invoice in the table, mark it as paid and then go to the end of the table and enter the new record. Surely there has to be a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Jessica

Comment: Why? Just grab the data you need for a new row at the time the status is changed, modify the values you need to change, and then do an INSERT to add the new row. There's no need to "search" or "go to the end". (The information missing from your question: a) How are you "marking it Paid"? On a form? b) How are you managing now to "create a new record"? On the form? In your code?

Comment: This seems like a bad database design.

Comment: So right now is the [Paid] field either empty (Null) or contains just the word 'Paid'?